# How much C# should I learn in order to work with CodedUI?

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I will switch to CodedUI from UFT for test automation and don't want to stay with VB any more. I am learning C# from Pluralsight currently and wondering how much and what level I should complete to be able to comfortably start CodedUI test development?

Any suggestion will be appreciated, especially someone has come from the similar situation.

Answer (score 5):

If you are concerned about learning too much, you are doing it WRONG.

The more you learn, the easier it will be for you to solve common problems.

We are getting questions DAILY here which would be solved trivially by having some (very little) programming experience - which is very obviously missing. And in some cases, even willingness to learn is missing. Possibly not in your case, so I decided to write an answer.

Common "rule of thumb" says it takes 10K hours to master something.

But also [Pareto principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle) says 80% of anything is irrelevant.

To be competent programmer, you need to learn few very different languages. [Blub Paradox](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html) is term describing how less-skilled programmer looks at more advanced languages, and why.

If learning Lisp is too much for you, try Python AND JavaScript. Hint: JavaScript is Lisp with C syntax.

So if you apply both 10K hours rule and Pareto principle: You can learn new language much faster, if you have the experience to tell which parts of the new language are same or can be ignored. But to gain this experience, you need to learn few languages before that, so...

I have no experience with CodedUI, but IMHO all the attempts to replace programmers and creating some magical UI allowing users to generate code are doomed for failure. I have personal experience with one such system/framework: Fit/FitNesse. Idea was to provide users with table-like language so they can write tests. It never happened, so programmers ended up writing code is bad limited DSL (domain-specific language) instead of the one they already mastered.  [Why Fit failed](http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/The-Problems-With-Acceptance-Testing.html) - and yes, we still have to maintain many test written in bad DSL.

Avoid that, use real language, they are free and make you more productive beyond first learning curve. At minimum, allow you to use Page Object design pattern, increasing QA test engineer productivity immensely.

See also [Greenspun's tenth rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_tenth_rule):

> Any sufficiently complicated C or Fortran program contains an ad-hoc, informally-specified, bug-ridden, slow implementation of half of Common Lisp

So instead of such half-implemented DSL (CodedUI, FitNesse), programmers prefer to have full (Turing-complete) language, which they can enhance as requirements evolve.

Comment: Thank you @PeterMasiar for the answer. That encourages me to be not afraid of spending too much time on learning C#. I have learned a few languages, including Basic, Pascal, C, COBOL, VBScript, Python, etc. but definitely not reaching 10K hours with only possible exception of COBOL.

Comment: You have decent programming background to see the semantics beyond syntax sugar. Learning C# will require you to learn new concept - OOP, Object-Oriented programming. Another hint: Python does it easier.

Comment: I can't find anywhere that mentions CodedUI Test with Python though.

Comment: I was talking about how to become more competent programmer, regardless of CodedUI or other tools/frameworks. Python is good tool to have in your toolbox for various text file processing and file management/scripting.

Comment: One task I needed to write in C#, I wrote "pilot" in Python first, using flexible Python dictionaries. Once I debugged the approach, I recoded it in C# (where dictionaries are possible but more tricky).

Comment: Personally I very much dislike coded UI as it's so rigid in the way a test has to be written it basically eliminates the redundant mapping usage or layered testing capabilities that help decrease the maintenance footprint.  Selenium(python supported) for web and Sikuli(python supported) for anything web or not would be my first choice on free products...good luck though, c# is a fun language to utilize...

Comment: I am just fed up with UFT, which I often encounter strange problems that can't get a reasonable explanation about. Especially for data driven frameworks, the scripts start to behave unexpected after about 10-20 iterations reading from the datasheet. So I am glad the company starts to switch to something else.

Comment: May the heavens bless you for mentioning why is Fit / Fitnesse and alike are a problem. I've been there and have similar experience. Since then I prefer writing DSL in programming language I use everyday.

Comment: @dzieciou - exactly. Instead of having hall-assed DSL, give me full flexible language and I will add helper functions as I need (not as some developer thought should be enough), and I could change them as my needs evolve.

Answer (score 2):

I think the basic level of coding skills will be sufficient however, I would completely avoid the record-and-playback/generated code approach in Coded UI. I also recently switched from UFT (VB Scripting) to Coded UI (C#). Not sure if you are planning to convert your existing UFT scripts to Coded UI or will be developing the hand coding framework from the start. I bought the following book from Amazon which used hand coding framework for the Web and Windows based applications.

[Hand Coding Coded UI by G.Suden](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1547000856)

Later on found out that if you buy from [this link](https://www.createspace.com/7208560) and use code U85UWTGF, you will get a 20% discount!

I personally think I you go through this book, you will need to learn a very basic level of C#. Moreover, the book has complete code for Web and Windows applications (Forms and WPF) which will be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

CodedUI generates code with record and playback. Most C# you will need is to change that code. I would [handcode CodedUI tests](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1055/hand-codedui-test-visual-studio-2013) and use the recorded as a helper for ideas how you can reach and interact with elements. Also if you are testing web-applications I would research if Selenium is not a better pick, as CodedUI is badly documented and not many people are using it, making it harder to get help on StackExchange.

I think programming fundamentals are more important than deep knowledge of C#. How you structure your code to be readable/understandable, maintainable and extendable will be of more value. Most of this is not language dependent.

Still do keep learning, here some books I would read about code structure

- [https://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882)
- [https://www.amazon.com/Software-Development-Principles-Patterns-Practices/dp/0135974445/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1489653146&sr=1-3&keywords=robert+c+martin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0135974445)

These will also help you to teach developers better coding practises as a QA engineer in a team.

Comment: [hand codedui test](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1055/hand-codedui-test-visual-studio-2013) is very helpful. That aligns with the approach I have been using as descriptive programming with UFT.